# How find all the contacts that have a ProLaw atom existing on them in Outlook regardless of the actual atom's value through Graph API

Tags: asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am using below API to get the contact which was deleted from App Database after stopping Service.

```
graphClient.User[emailId]
           .Contacts
           .Request()
           .Filter($"singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq '{GlobalConstants.PrimaryKeyMapiId}')")
           .Expand($"singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{GlobalConstants.PrimaryKeyMapiId}')"  )
           .GetAsync()
           .Result;
```

Its throwing exception , Please sugest what will be the solution for this

Comment: Could you please share the exception?

Comment: Code: ErrorInvalidUrlQueryFilter
Message: The filter expression for $filter does not match to a single extended property and a value restriction.
ClientRequestId: d3ecf4d4-ba1a-4acb-bc98-964dacd417bd

Comment: This is actually when Contact does not exit in database. I have to delete that contact which is deleted after stopping the Services and delete entry from  exchangetables

Comment: I test it in my side and with url like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/contacts?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00040ec6ac6e} Name Fun' and ep/value eq 'Food')`, it worked, convert to SDK, you can see my post below

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the exception

```
The filter expression for $filter does not match to a single extended property
and a value restriction.
```

You need to add `value` restriction to filter.

```
graphClient.User[emailId]
       .Contacts
       .Request()
       .Filter($"singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq '{GlobalConstants.PrimaryKeyMapiId}' and ep/value eq 'Food')")
       .Expand($"singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{GlobalConstants.PrimaryKeyMapiId}')"  )
       .GetAsync()
       .Result;
```

Or you can try to omit `.Filter()` method because the filter itself is specified in `.Expand()` method

```
graphClient.User[emailId]
           .Contacts
           .Request()
           .Expand($"singleValueExtendedProperties($filter=id eq '{GlobalConstants.PrimaryKeyMapiId}')"  )
           .GetAsync()
           .Result;
```

Comment: Its not showing error but  finding all contact, but I need to find contact which I first created in database through graph API and than delete the contact from database

Answer (score 1):

```
string a = "String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00040ec6ac6e} Name Fun";
            var res = await graphClient.Users["tinywang@tenant_name.onmicrosoft.com"]
                                .Contacts
                                .Request()
                                .Filter($"singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq '{a}' and ep/value eq 'Food')").GetAsync();
```

[image]

Per my searching, when we want to add a filter on `singleValueExtendedProperties`, then we can follow [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/singlevaluelegacyextendedproperty-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#get-resource-instances-that-include-numeric-extended-properties-matching-a-filter).

[image]

Then per my test, if I sent a request like `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/contacts?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00040ec6ac6e} Name Fun')` it will had issue like below

[image]

So we have to call api like this: `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/user_id/contacts?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/Any(ep: ep/id eq 'String {66f5a359-4659-4830-9070-00040ec6ac6e} Name Fun' and ep/value eq 'Food')`

[image]

Comment: If we apply to  filter for any null value

Comment: To get resource instances that have certain extended properties, use the $filter query parameter and apply an eq operator on the id property. In addition, for numeric extended properties, apply one of the following operators on the value property: eq, ne,ge, gt, le, or lt. For string-typed extended properties, apply a contains, startswith, eq, or ne operator on value.

Comment: This is mentioned in the document, so I think it may be supported. So, what do you mean `filter for any null value`?